# Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found

Tags: android, firebase

Recently after some version updates on gradle files, the following error started to appear when the app is opened:

```
08-04 17:27:31.190: W/FirebaseApp(32757): Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
08-04 17:27:31.190: I/FirebaseInitProvider(32757): FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
```

This is how my build.gradle looks like (android):

```
...
buildscript {
    
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.9'
    }
}
...
```

Answer (score 3):

I downgraded the `com.google.gms:google-services` from `4.3.9` to `4.3.8` and the error was fixed.

Comment: haha thanks, started a new project today and same issue, minor downgrade fixed it!

Comment: same here, new project started but from version 4.4.0 to 4.3.8. Thank you so much.